# web api - return complex domain object from repository layer

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, repository-pattern

I am working on a project which is currently at its initial stage so, I can make some architectural change at this point. This is more a design related issue. So here it is:

I am building a Web API + EF + .net framework + Repository pattern.

So I have a repository layer which return data from database context.following is snippet of linq in repository layer:

```
from custVerExt in _context.VERIFICATIONEXTs.Where(x => x.ID == custVer.ID).DefaultIfEmpty()
from zref_vcode in _context.LISTDATAs.Where(x => x.ID == custVerExt.VERIFICATIONCD).DefaultIfEmpty()
from refUi_vcode in _context.LBLTXTs.Where(x => x.ID == zref_vcode.REFLISTDATANMLBLID).DefaultIfEmpty()
from zref_tcode in _context.LISTDATAs.Where(x => x.ID == custVerExt.TYPEID).DefaultIfEmpty()
from refUi_tcode in _context.LBLTXTs.Where(x => x.ID == zref_tcode.REFLISTDATANMLBLID).DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Now here I want both the object `refUi_vcode` & `refUi_tcode` which is of type `_context.LBLTXTs` to be returned.

something like `select refUi_vcode.name,refUi_tcode.name`

I do not want my repository to return DTO's(its a job of my service layer) hence I want to return some customer domain object.
Now, I came up with two structures for my domain object. In case listed above, if I want to return value from the same table twice, I can create two instances of the same object **OR** create two separate properties which I want from those two objects.

Code sample:

```
public class CustDomainObj
{
public LBLTXTs obj1 {get;set;}
public LBLTXTs obj2 {get;set;}
}
//OR
public class CustDomainObj
{
public string obj1 {get;set;}
public string obj2 {get;set;}
}
```

My DTO look like this:

```
public CustDTO
{
public string vname{get;set;}
public string cname{get;set;}
}
```

**Questions:**

- I am not sure if my repository - domain object return policy is the good bet in long run. If it is which way should I go? (Multiple instances of the same Entity object or just return required properties)
- If I return required properties in the domain object, wouldn't it be a kind of DTO structure?
- If both of my approaches are not correct, could anyone guide me with an appropriate example?

Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I think that repository-domain object return policy is a good bet because :-

  1. It will abide by separation of concerns (SoC) design principle i.e your repository layer will deal with domain objects and service layer with DTO.
  2. Keeps the code unit testable so u can find if it breaks at repository or service layer.
- If you use repository-domain object return policy, its better to just return required properties as there is no need of other properties of the Entity and would reduce redundancy.
- And for your second question,there is a difference between DTO and domain objects. DTO are what may contain information required across different layers.Lets say your service layer requires to return a customers address details and work details(both are domain objects).Then the DTO will seem like this :-

DTO:-

```
public class CustDTO
{
public string address1{get;set;}
public string address2{get;set;}
public string company{get;set;}
public string location{get;set;}
}
```

Domain objects:-

```
public class CustAddress
{
public string address1{get;set;}
public string address2{get;set;}
}

public class CustWorkDetials
{
public string company{get;set;}
public string location{get;set;}
}
```

So basically DTO are used when u want to pass a single aggregate class of two or more classes of given layer as return value to layer above it in stack.

Comment: I got your point of returning domain objects from repository. Though i did not understand what do you mean by return only required properties? For e.g. In my case, lets say i am returning object of type `LBLTXTs` it would by default have all the properties inside it.

Comment: @Shaggy what i mean to say is that in your case object of type `LBLTXTs` may have some properties which may not be required by your Domain object. For e.g lets say your `LBLTXTs` has properties `name` and `location`, but your DO requires just `name` property.And in case your DO requires all the properties then u can return the `LBLTXTs` complete object.I hope this helps.